# Change product links in cart

Tags: 7, ubercart

How do I change the link for products in the cart, currently they link to the product nodes but I'd like them to link to a custom view?

I can create a custom template, page--cart.tpl.php, but I don't know what the original code would be, and adding the following displays just the cart on the page, no other blocks:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

I'd like to be able to create a custom template, to give me more control, but I only really need to change the link to the product page and the product image.